# is there any solution to find the time span between two time duration

Tags: c#, math, asp.net-web-api, time-difference

I have two times like 100:45 and 395:50
I need to find the subtraction and addition between these two times in the asp.net web application

I will expect like this 100:45+395:50=496:35 and 100:45-395:50=295:05

Comment: Have you tried using `TimeSpan`?

Comment: what does 100:45 mean - 100 hours and 45 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

assuming the times are given in a string. then you can split the times to get the equivalent minutes. now it becomes a simple mathematics problem and now perform addition and subtraction accordingly.

```
string time = "100:45";
string[] parts = time.Split(':');
int hours = int.Parse(parts[0]);
int minutes = int.Parse(parts[1]);
int totalMinutes = hours * 60 + minutes;
```

so for your case

```
int mins1 = 100 * 60 + 45;
int mins2 = 395 * 60 + 50;
int totalMinutes = mins1 + mins2;
int totalHours = totalMinutes / 60;
int remainingMinutes = totalMinutes % 60;
string sum = $"{totalHours}:{remainingMinutes}";
```

use the same concept to get the subtraction as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert times to `TimeSpan.FromMinutes` and to get the desired output using `TimeSpan.TotalHours` and `TimeSpan.Minutes`

```
string s1 = "100:45";
string s2 = "395:50";

TimeSpan spWorkMin = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(int.Parse(s1.Split(':')[0]) * 60 + 
                                          int.Parse(s2.Split(':')[0]) * 60 +
                                          int.Parse(s1.Split(':')[1]) + 
                                          int.Parse(s2.Split(':')[1]));
var sum =string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", (int)tSum.TotalHours, tSum.Minutes);//496:35

TimeSpan tsub = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(int.Parse(s1.Split(':')[0]) * 60 - 
                                     int.Parse(s2.Split(':')[0]) * 60 +
                                     int.Parse(s1.Split(':')[1]) - 
                                     int.Parse(s2.Split(':')[1]));
var subtract = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", Math.Abs((int)tsub.TotalHours),Math.Abs(tsub.Minutes)); //295:05
```

Answer (score 0):

TimeSpan do the trick

```
        TimeSpan ts1 = new TimeSpan(0, 100, 45);
        TimeSpan ts2 = new TimeSpan(0, 395, 50);

        var tsResult = ts1 + ts2;
        string outPut = string.Format("{0}:{1}", Math.Floor(tsResult.TotalMinutes), tsResult.Seconds);
```

Comment: ts1 + ts2 retutn  `{08:16:35}`the output should be this `496:35`